# How to transform mutable map with certain data to array list?

Tags: kotlin

I have a mutable map with key of week days and values of time range

```
items: MutableMap<String, MutableList<Period>>
Period(start, end)
For example: monday: [Period = {start: "11:00", end: "12:12"}, Period =  {start: "15:00", end: "16:12"}], tuesday: [] and etc
```

I need to transform this map to array list like that:

```
[(Period = {start: "11:00", end: "12:12"}, [monday, tuesday, friday]), (Period={start: "15:00", end: "16:12"}, [sunday, monday, thursday]) etc]
```

```
 have a map like "monday": [
                    {"end": "13:29", "start": "00:30" }
                ],
                "friday": [],
                "saturday": [],
                "wednesday": [
                    {"end": "04:29","start": "02:30"}
                ],
                "tuesday": [
                    {"end": "04:29","start": "02:30"},
                    { "end": "13:29", "start": "12:30"}
                ],
                "sunday": [],
                "thursday": [
                    {"end": "04:29","start": "02:30" },
                    { "end": "14:29","start": "05:30"}
                ]
need to transform to [(Period: {"end": "04:29","start": "02:30" }, [tuesday, wednesday, thursday]), (Period: { "end": "14:29","start": "05:30"}, [thursday]), (Period: {"end": "13:29", "start": "00:30" }, [monday, tuesday]) ]
```

to array of smth like that
Could anyone help with that please?

this is the method of how i need to transform

```
fun transformMap(items: MutableMap<String, MutableList<Period>>): ArrayList<Pair<Period, List<String>>> {

}
```

Comment: It is not Kotlin.

Comment: Could you please add a sample map with values and the exact desired output along with your attempts to solve this?

Comment: @deHaar added sample map, and in whats way i need to transform it, please check

Comment: You are having JSON objects, but no `Period` object, right? Can you show us how you are transforming / parsing it to Kotlin?

Comment: @deHaar added a method, i have a map need to return array list by somehow transforming data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
fun transformMap(items: MutableMap<String, MutableList<Period>>): ArrayList<Pair<Period, List<String>>> {
    //for each day and its list of periods, create a list of period-day pairs
    //and join the individual lists into a single list
    val periodAndDayPairs = items.flatMap {
        val day = it.key
        val periods = it.value
        periods.map { period -> Pair(period, day) }
    }
    //create a map where key is the period and value is a list of period-day pairs with the same period
    val periodToPeriodAndDayPairs = periodAndDayPairs.groupBy { it.first }
    //modify values in that map - extract only the day from the period-day pair
    val periodToDays = periodToPeriodAndDayPairs.mapValues {
        it.value.map { it.second }
    }
    //finally, convert each map entry into a period-days pair and store it into an ArrayList to match requested function signature
    return periodToDays.mapTo(ArrayList(), { Pair(it.key, it.value)})
}
```

Disclaimer: The code is intentionally verbose so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: you can simplify `items.flatMap { (days, periods) -> ... }` and  `val periodToDays = periodAndDayPairs.groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })`, also there is `toPair()` extension method for `Map.Entry`

Comment: it worked the way i wanted to, thanks a lot @mcernak